# Passing a php/mysql value to a div, accessible from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am creating a `<div>` that represents a table row in sql, with php. Fine.
Then I am using a javascript function to test the values of the div (position, width etc).Fine.
But I need to pass another value to the div to be checked by the function. It is there in the database but I don't know if there is a (simple) way to do it. Ideally it would look something like this.

```
<div id='plumber5' class='plumber' style='width:50px;left:100px' value='numericValue'>Derek</div>
```

The inline styles are generated in php, and can't think of a way of passing a numeric value other than by style (width, height etc) that js can detect.

eg.

```
<script>
a=document.getElementById('plumber5');
if (a.style.width=>75){
execute something here}
</script>
```

Instead of using style as a source for testing

Its very troubling!
Thanks

EDIT - solution

```
function checkData($type){  
    a = document.getElementsByClassName($type);
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
    if (a[i].getAttribute('data-dob') >= sessionStorage.Value) {
    // execute something here
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Without using AJAX if poss

Comment: You have an error here btw: `style='width='50px;left=100px'` (one extra single quote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the data attribute of HTML5 to add some custom data to your HTML tags:

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Example:

```
<div data-value='10' id='plumber5' class='plumber' style='width: 50px; left: 100px;'>
    Derek
</div>
```

You can get the value like this:

```
<script>
    a = document.getElementById('plumber5');
    if (a.getAttribute('data-value') => 75) {
        // execute something here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi that's great but can Javascript test that value similarly to the above example?

Comment: Added an example how to do this.

Comment: I'm using getElementsByClassName to test for each element with a class name, but it doesn't seem to work - I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getAttribute', code pasted above

Comment: fixed! (was missing [i] from the object node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-` attributes this way:

```
<div id='plumber5' class='plumber' style='width: 50px; left: 100px'
     data-value='numericValue'>Derek</div>
```

***Note:** HTML5 Data Attributes are supported only in modern browsers like IE 9+, Chrome 12+, Firefox 5+.*

Notice that you have an error in the `style` attribute. Replace:

```
style='width=50px;left=100px'
```

With:

```
style='width: 50px; left: 100px'
```

Comment: Mention browser compatibility for the data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports `data-*` tag attributes, so you can use:

```
<div id='plumber5' class='plumber' data-value='numericValue' data-myothervalue='otherOne'>
    Derek
</div>
```

EDIT

Since it looks messy in comments, here's how to access the example values:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('plumber5'); 
var myVal = myDiv.getAttribute('data-value');         // 'numericValue'
var myVal2 = myDiv.getAttribute('data-myothervalue'); // 'otherOne'
```

Comment: Thanks, Shomz. That is a revelation! I am using html5 anyway. Can this be tested by javascript simply?

Comment: Absolutely! `var div = document.getElementById('plumber5');
var myVal = div.getAttribute('data-value'); var myVal2 = div.getAttribute('data-myothervalue');`

Answer (score 1):

If your audience doesn't support HTML5, you can embed a div like:

```
<div id="plumber5" class="plumber" style="width:50px;left:100px">
    Derek
    <div style="display: none">numericValue</div>
</div>
```

That would hide the value from view, but would allow you to access it view Javascript.